# Hashmap value not updating on consecutive inserts [Rust]

Tags: rust

I have a struct that contains various Routers. Mostly hashmaps. But for this specific hashmap, the values are not updating after insertion. There is no delete function. Just an insert function(shown below).

This is the main struct

```rust
pub struct Router {
....
    web_socket_routes: Arc<RwLock<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, (PyFunction, u8)>>>>,
}
```

This is a getter

```rust
    #[inline]
    pub fn get_web_socket_map(
        &self,
    ) -> &Arc<RwLock<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, (PyFunction, u8)>>>> {
        &self.web_socket_routes
    }
```

This is the insert method

```rust
    pub fn add_websocket_route(
        &mut self,
        route: &str,
        connect_route: (Py<PyAny>, bool, u8),
        close_route: (Py<PyAny>, bool, u8),
        message_route: (Py<PyAny>, bool, u8),
    ) {
        let table = self.get_web_socket_map();
        let (connect_route_function, connect_route_is_async, connect_route_params) = connect_route;
        let (close_route_function, close_route_is_async, close_route_params) = close_route;
        let (message_route_function, message_route_is_async, message_route_params) = message_route;

        let insert_in_router =
            |handler: Py<PyAny>, is_async: bool, number_of_params: u8, socket_type: &str| {
                let function = if is_async {
                    PyFunction::CoRoutine(handler)
                } else {
                    PyFunction::SyncFunction(handler)
                };

                let mut route_map = HashMap::new();
                route_map.insert(socket_type.to_string(), (function, number_of_params));

                println!("socket type is {:?} {:?}", table, route);
                table.write().unwrap().insert(route.to_string(), route_map);
            };

        insert_in_router(
            connect_route_function,
            connect_route_is_async,
            connect_route_params,
            "connect",
        );

        insert_in_router(
            close_route_function,
            close_route_is_async,
            close_route_params,
            "close",
        );

        insert_in_router(
            message_route_function,
            message_route_is_async,
            message_route_params,
            "message",
        );
    }
```

After all the 3 `insert_in_router` calls, `web_socket_routes` only contains the insertion of the last `insert_in_router` call?

I have tried changing the `Arc<RwLock<` for a generic `DashMap` but I am still facing the same issues.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Thank you @user4815162342. `table.write().unwrap().entry(route.to_string()).or_default().insert(socket_type.to_string(), (function, number_of_params))` works for me :D

Do you want to create an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closure unconditionally creates a new inner hashmap each time, which it uses as value in the outer hashmap. However, it inserts it into the outer hashmap under the same key (`route.to_string()`) all three times, which results in each insert overwriting the previous one(s).

You need to implement a logic that will create a new inner hashmap only if one is missing under that key, otherwise look up the existing one. Then it should insert the value into the inner hashmap, either the freshly created one, or the one looked up. In Rust this is conveniently done using the entry API:

```
table
    .write()
    .unwrap()
    .entry(route.to_string())
    .or_default()
    .insert(socket_type.to_string(), (function, number_of_params));
```